# Import of Arrays util not working

Tags: java

I need to import the Arrays utilities for use in some code I am writing, however, when I type in "import java.util.Arrays" , the word "Arrays" does not turn blue. I'm guessing this means I can not import it but why is this? Since the word does not turn blue does that indicate that I do not have the package or whatever? Should it not be included in the java files I downloaded when installing Jcreator?

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: EDIT: Sorry I had Utils written in the question, but I already had java.util.Arrays; written in my code but it is not working

Comment: Please Post your code and check if your installed jdk is used for your project.

Answer (score 2):

the package is `util` not `utils` so import

`import java.util.Arrays`

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `import java.util.Arrays;` or `import java.util.*`. The latter imports all the classes within the `util` package.